# UNION strange behaviour - MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

We have two simple queries

1.

```
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = 91
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = (SELECT [bankID] FROM [bank] WHERE bankID = 83)
```

which returns as expected:

```
bankID
1    91
2    83
```

2.

```
SELECT TOP 1 bankID 
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = 91
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = (SELECT [bankID] FROM [bank] WHERE bankID > 82 AND bankID < 84)
```

which returns:

```
bankID
1    83
2    91
```

Order is reversed. Why?

When we change the condition in first query of union the results are in line with expectations.

```
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = 42
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = (SELECT [bankID] FROM [bank] WHERE bankID = 83)
```

---

```
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = 42
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 bankID
FROM [bank] WHERE [bankID] = (SELECT [bankID] FROM [bank] WHERE bankID > 82 AND bankID < 84)
```

The result of both is:

```
       bankID
    1    42
    2    83
```

Again, why?

SQLServer 2012

Comment: If you don't have an order by any order is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Order is not guaranteed,until you specify order by .If you want preserve order ,do some thing like below

```
select * from  A
union all
select * from b order by id --now you will get output order based on id
```

**Update:**
All RDBMS are based on Settheory.So elements in a set dont have any order.TSQL is also based on set theory in so many aspects.Tables should be considered as a set and rows in a table are not stored in any order.SQL is free to retrieve rows in any order based on many criteria like indexes,cold cache,plan...

So coming to your example union all of two sets is again a set and you are not guaranteed to get same order every time

```
select 1 as t
union all
select 2
union all
select 0
```

**Output:**

```
t
--
1
2
0
```

you are not guarnteed to get same order everytime until you order by..

```
select 1 as t
union all
select 2
union all
select 0 order by t
```

Same goes for order by in CTE's ,Derived tables

```
 with cte
as
(
   select top 100% from table order by somecolumn
)
select * from cte
```

Even though you order in cte,you are not guarnetted to get default order every time,until you do order by in outer clause too

```
with cte
as
(
   select top 100% from table order by somecolumn
)
select * from cte order by somecolumn
```